# Running hyperledger caliper to test my local hyperledger fabric network

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-caliper

Im using hyperledger caliper to benchmark my local fabric network but i have some errors which lead to missing some values from report such as successful transactions and latency. any one can help me to fix these errors? as follow :

```
toor@toor-VirtualBox:~/caliper-workspace$ **npx caliper launch manager --caliper-workspace ./ --caliper-networkconfig networks/networkConfig.yaml --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/myAssetBenchmark.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-enabled**


2022-04-20T07:42:51.316Z - error: [RoundRobinQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
    at RoundRobinQueryHandler.evaluate (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/roundrobinqueryhandler.js:66:23)
    at Transaction.evaluate (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:319:49)
       
2022.04.20-10:42:51.318 error [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway]   Failed to perform query transaction [ReadAsset] using arguments [0_8],  with error: FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
    at RoundRobinQueryHandler.evaluate (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/roundrobinqueryhandler.js:66:23)
  

2022-04-20T07:42:57.401Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    at newEndorsementError (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:74:12)
    at getResponsePayload (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:41:23)
    at Transaction.submit (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:255:28)
    at async V2FabricGateway._submitOrEvaluateTransaction (/home/toor/caliper-workspace/node_modules/@hyperledger/caliper-fabric/lib/connector-versions/v2/FabricGateway.js:376:26)

2022.04.20-10:42:57.509 error [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway]   Failed to perform submit transaction [DeleteAsset] using arguments [1_2],  with error: Error: No valid responses from any peers.

2022.04.20-10:42:57.759 info  [caliper] [connectors/v2/FabricGateway]   disconnecting gateway for user User1
2022.04.20-10:42:57.764 info  [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Worker#1 finished Round#0
2022.04.20-10:43:02.773 info  [caliper] [default-observer]  Resetting txCount indicator count
2022.04.20-10:43:02.777 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    ### Test result ###
2022.04.20-10:43:02.835 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    
+-----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Name      | Succ | Fail | Send Rate (TPS) | Max Latency (s) | Min Latency (s)  | Avg Latency (s) | Throughput (TPS) |
|-----------|------|------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------|-----------------|------------------|
| readAsset | 0    | 1693 | 57.2            | 0.00            | 9007199254740.99 | -               | 57.2             |
+-----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+

2022.04.20-10:43:02.842 info  [caliper] [round-orchestrator]    Finished round 1 (readAsset) in 30.138 seconds
2022.04.20-10:43:02.844 info  [caliper] [monitor.js]    Stopping all monitors
2022.04.20-10:43:02.855 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    ### All test results ###
2022.04.20-10:43:02.869 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    
+-----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Name      | Succ | Fail | Send Rate (TPS) | Max Latency (s) | Min Latency (s)  | Avg Latency (s) | Throughput (TPS) |
|-----------|------|------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------|-----------------|------------------|
| readAsset | 0    | 1693 | 57.2            | 0.00            | 9007199254740.99 | -               | 57.2             |
+-----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+

2022.04.20-10:43:02.987 info  [caliper] [report-builder]    Generated report with path /home/toor/caliper-workspace/report.html
2022.04.20-10:43:02.988 info  [caliper] [monitor.js]    Stopping all monitors
2022.04.20-10:43:02.990 info  [caliper] [worker-orchestrator]   Sending exit message to connected workers
2022.04.20-10:43:02.991 info  [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Worker#0 is exiting
2022.04.20-10:43:02.994 info  [caliper] [worker-message-handler]    Worker#1 is exiting
2022.04.20-10:43:02.995 info  [caliper] [round-orchestrator]    Benchmark finished in 42.057 seconds. Total rounds: 1. Successful rounds: 1. Failed rounds: 0.
2022.04.20-10:43:02.996 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]    Skipping end command due to benchmark flow conditioning
2022.04.20-10:43:02.997 info  [caliper] [cli-launch-manager]    Benchmark successfully finished
```

my network configration file is : networkConfig.yaml

```js
name: Calier test
version: "2.0.0"

caliper:
  blockchain: fabric
  sutOptions:
    mutualTls: false

channels:
  - channelName: mychannel
    contracts:
    - id: basic

organizations:
  - mspid: Org1MSP
    identities:
      certificates:
      - name: 'User1'
        clientPrivateKey:
          path: '/home/toor/EHRUsingBlockchain-master/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/114aab0e76bf0c78308f89efc4b8c9423e31568da0c340ca187a9b17aa9a4457_sk'
        clientSignedCert:
          path: '/home/toor/EHRUsingBlockchain-master/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem'

    connectionProfile:
      path: '/home/toor/EHRUsingBlockchain-master/DevServer_connection.json'
      discover: false
```

and benchmarks file : myAssetBenchmark.yaml

```js
test:
    name: basic-contract-benchmark
    description: test benchmark
    workers:
      type: local
      number: 2
    rounds:
      - label: readAsset
        description: Read asset benchmark
        txDuration: 30
        rateControl:
          type: fixed-load
          opts:
            transactionLoad: 2
        workload:
          module: workload/readAsset.js
          arguments:
            assets: 10
            contractId: basic
```

and my workload file : readAsset.js

```js
'use strict';

const { WorkloadModuleBase } = require('@hyperledger/caliper-core');

class MyWorkload extends WorkloadModuleBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext) {
        await super.initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext);

        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Creating asset ${assetID}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: 'CreateAsset',
                invokerIdentity: 'User1',
                contractArguments: [assetID,'blue','20','penguin','500'],
                readOnly: false
            };

            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }

    async submitTransaction() {
        const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.roundArguments.assets);
        const myArgs = {
            contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
            contractFunction: 'ReadAsset',
            invokerIdentity: 'User1',
            contractArguments: [`${this.workerIndex}_${randomId}`],
            readOnly: true
        };

        await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(myArgs);
    }

    async cleanupWorkloadModule() {
        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Deleting asset ${assetID}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: 'DeleteAsset',
                invokerIdentity: 'User1',
                contractArguments: [assetID],
                readOnly: false
            };

            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }
}

function createWorkloadModule() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have setup a hyperledger fabric 1.2 network and deployed a hyperledger composer business network. Hyperledger composer is end of life now (and so is hyperledger fabric 1.x). Caliper doesn't support benchmarking hyperledger composer networks anymore either.

The approach you tried seems to have come from the tutorial which uses hyperledger fabric 2.2 and a deployed chaincode of asset-transfer-basic.

Caliper workload modules have to have knowledge of the implemented chaincode so workload modules are bound to the chaincode they benchmark. Therefore you can't just take the caliper component of the tutorial and try to run it against any hyperledger fabric network with any chaincode deployed, it isn't going to work. Hyperledger Composer is a special case as it had specialist chaincode that required a specialist client component in order to be able to interact which means that caliper needs specialist composer support to work (ie the fabric component of caliper cannot talk to a hyperledger composer business network deployed onto hyperledger fabric).

The last version of caliper to support hyperledger composer looks to be 0.2.0 but the documentation is minimal by the looks of it so I think you are going to be very much your own if you still want to pursue benchmarking and end of life environment with an end of life version of caliper.

Comment: Thank you david_k for your response. did you mean just i need change caliper cli to 0.2. using  $ npm install --only=prod @hyperledger/caliper-cli@0.2 and            $ npx caliper bind --caliper-bind-sut fabric:1.4   or need more steps ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it requires a lot more indepth work to do what you want and you can't follow the fabric tutorial either. I don't know if there is any old documentation about how to do this but I see that the caliper docs for v0.2.0 on using composer give very little detail. As all these components are end of life you are lilkely to be on your own trying to figure all this out. I've never used caliper for anything apart from benchmarking hyperledger fabric and chaincode I've never tried to benchmark a hyperledger composer application